# Convert slim to html for use as post content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have a blog written in rails and I write the templates in slim. I was thinking it would be awesome to write my blog post content slim in my textarea box and convert it to html before I save it to the database

Is this possible and if so how can I accomplish it?

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think I'd like to store the slim in the DB and render it to HTML when the page is requested. That way when I go back to edit the page it is in nice pretty slim markup.

Comment: good call on that one, that is what I will want

Answer (score 4):

The documentation [says](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#tilt):

> Slim uses Tilt to compile the generated code. If you want to use the
> Slim template directly, you can use the Tilt interface.

And provides the following examples:

```
Tilt.new['template.slim'].render(scope)
Slim::Template.new('template.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)
Slim::Template.new(optional_option_hash) { source }.render(scope)
```

And I am pretty sure that something like the following also works:

```
Slim::Template.new(template_path).render
```

The complete gist of the aforementioned line is to be found [here](https://gist.github.com/marvinahv/5894328).

Comment: my only issue with this is I will have to write the content to a file temporarily. I would like to be able to input slim as a string instead of a file name.

Comment: This is great! Thanks, I've been searching for this for over an hour. This was perfect: `html_string = Slim::Template.new('/path/to/my/template.html.slim').render`